# Raspberry pi3 - Cannot show desktop

Tags: ssh, display, vnc

After some updates on my RPI3 running openmediavault, I cannot vnc into the system. I have tried them all by changing any resolution, enabling vnc in the raspi-confing settings and even mv .Xauthority but with no chance. I can easily ssh into it but I cannot vnc.

Comment: The instructions state "When selecting a Raspbian Image, for best possible compatibility with OMV5, don't use an image with a desktop." Why did you ignore this?

Comment: to be fair, I followed the instructions and everything worked except for the desktop. The desktop was always there with the OMV and everything was working fine before the upgrade.

Comment: I don't know how it happened but apparently it started working again. After a distro-upgrade and another resolution reset having vnc enable. The system is able to run vnc once again.